# How to get interactivity with maven release plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

The maven release plugin in Jenkins prompts you for input when doing a release:prepare.  It'll give you a suggested value, but you also have the choice to override that suggested value to put your own value.  How can you do this same thing when writing a Jenkins pipeline in groovy?  The only thing that I've found online is -> https://gist.github.com/cyrille-leclerc/552e3103139557e0196a.  This method is strictly command and just gives batch mode with no user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter definitions passed to the `input` step can specify default values. Try it in *Snippet Generator*.